# Comparten ID pero solo funciona en el primero

Tags: javascript, ajax

Sólo me reconoce los atributos y valores del primer ID, no respeta los siguientes. 
Muestro mi código a continuación:

**index.php**

```
<button type="button" id="boton_uno" class="boton-estado">Boton 1</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button type="button" id="boton_dos" class="boton-estado">Boton 2</button>
```

**funcionalidad.js**

```
$('#boton_uno').attr('estado', opcion1);
$('#boton_dos').attr('estado', opcion2);

$('#boton_uno').html(label1);
$('#boton_dos').html(label2);

var boton1 = document.querySelector("#boton_uno");
var boton2 = document.querySelector("#boton_dos");

if (estado == 0) {
    boton1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    boton2.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
} else if (estado == 1) {
    boton1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    boton2.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
} else if (estado == 2) {
    boton1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    boton2.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}

$('.boton-estado').click(function(){
    //aqui va codigo...
    }
});
```

Código del .js : https://jsfiddle.net/omaza1990/dakmcouv/

Comment: No se entiende bien, donde estan los elementos que comparten id? ¿Te refieres a la clase? puedes aclararlo?

Comment: Los elementos que comparten id son "boton_uno" "boton_dos" por cada ID. Entonces me funciona el código de funcionalidad.js pero sólo para el primer ID, cuando busca el segundo ID o el tercera o el noveno... no realiza el código de funcionalidad.js debido a que el ID es el mismo (duplicado, y el ID debe ser único). Espero haberme explicado.

Comment: A ver is ya con esto: [ver ejemplo](http://jsbin.com/boliyo/edit?html,js,console,output) te soluciona algo...

Comment: @aldanux ese no es mi problema, eso me lo realiza en el primer usuario, primer elemento, pero en los demás no me lo reconoce.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tienes un problema de conceptos.

Los ID son los identificadores de cada uno de los elementos. Son **únicos** y no se deben repetir en más de un elemento del `HTML`. No son obligatorios.

Las clases sirven para asignar estilos a más de un elemento dentro del HTML. Tampoco son obligatorias.

Una vez dicho esto, al tener una clase, y usando `JQuery`, si quieres referirte al elemento que has pulsado, en este caso, un botón, deberías usar la palabra reservada `this`. El elemento `this` también existe para `Javascript`.

Mediante esta palabra haces referencia al elemento que acabas de pulsar (en caso de que fuera otro tipo de evento haría referencia al elemento que ha lanzado ese evento). Por tanto, para que saque los atributos de los elementos que pulsas deberías de usar esta palabra.

Ejemplo de uso en el que al pulsar cada botón cambio el color de los mismos y saco por pantalla su texto correspondiente:

```js
$(".boton-estado").click(function() {
     $(this).css('color', 'blue');
     
     alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="boton_uno" class="boton-estado">Boton 1</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button type="button" id="boton_dos" class="boton-estado">Boton 2</button>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49007/discussion-on-answer-by-error404-comparten-id-pero-solo-funciona-en-el-primero).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ¿Cómo se trasladan? Estaba intentando crear un chat pero no sabía como.

Comment: Ya lo creé. Gracias Luiggi

Comment: Luego de varios comentarios en una publicación, cuando quieres agregar uno nuevo aparece la opción para crear una sala de chat (debo buscar la imagen de eso). Pero no se preocupen, en mi comentario está la sala de chat donde se han trasladado sus comentarios, usen esa.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sí, yo estaba buscando ese mensaje pero no me salió a pesar de tener un montón. Gracias por crear la sala ^^

Answer (score 0):

creo que funciona, talves tu variable estado sea el problema

```js
var boton1 = document.querySelector("#boton_uno");
var boton2 = document.querySelector("#boton_dos");
var estado=2;
if (estado == 0) {
    boton1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    boton2.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
} else if (estado == 1) {
    boton1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    boton2.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
} else if (estado == 2) {
    boton1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    boton2.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="boton_uno" class="boton-estado">Boton 1</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button type="button" id="boton_dos" class="boton-estado">Boton 2</button>
```

Comment: El error lo tengo en que sólo me funciona para el primer elemento, para los demás no. Creo que es porque repito/duplico el id, y los IDs son únicos para más de un elemento, así que... ¿cómo podría modificarlo?

Comment: @omaza1990 en el codigo que puse no hay repeticion de id

Comment: al crear el modal dentro de un while para cada una de los usuarios/ids/filas/rows que existan pues entonces se generan muchas ids iguales para los botones. Pero eso te vale para una td, no para varias tds... eso para una td también me funciona a mi, pero cuando quiero comprobar más de una td me casca porque se repite la id de los botones.